# HTML Pagination for Editable Docs

Tags: html, pagination

I want to write a HTML application which has a div

```
contenteditable=true
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

While the user is typing content in this div, and he runs out of space (height) - i want the content should move to the next div (another div below this one)

How can this be achieved? I could listen to events on the div and keep checking the height (whether it has grown above 200px), and then what?

I could find many solutions for non-editable documents, but none for my problem.

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the height of the content of your div, and if it's overflow a certain height, move the content in another div.

To do that, you have to use some javascript, which will check the content size at every keydown() and create your new divs if the content is too big for your div. The key here is to listen and execute this scenario at each keydown :

- Check if the height of the content is bigger than 200px
- If it's true, create a new div and put the content in it
- Append a new item to the pagination (and possibly a way to show the div created)
- Clean the editable div

Be careful that your user doesn't lost inputs (one or two key inputs for example) during this process...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is a correct solution, but it is too burdened. I was looking for some support where this comes for free? Someone must have done something similar sometime.